# Graph Api: search file for exact match

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I have a file called "**ABC_file1.docx**".
I want to perform a search of a specific file name in a specific folder.

My code is:

```
            var fileName = "ABC_file1.docx";

            var files = _graphClient
              .Drives[<My_Drive_ID>]
              .Root
              .ItemWithPath("My_Sub_Folder")
              .Search(fileName)
              .Request()
              .GetAsync()
              .Result;
```

Unfortunately this works not only for my file, but also for a similar file name, like "**ABC_ABC_file1.docx**", and that's not what i need.

How can I search for exact match?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried leveraging documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/keyword-queries-and-search-conditions?view=o365-worldwide#searchable-site-properties) for searchable site properties and see if this helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution and seems that the "Search" method is not what it needs for exact match file search.

It's better to use "Filter" rather than "Search" like this:

```
            var fileName = "ABC_file1.docx";

            var files = _graphClient
              .Drives[<My_Drive_ID>]
              .Root
              .ItemWithPath("My_Sub_Folder")
              .Children
              .Request()
              .Filter($"name eq '{fileName}'")
              .GetAsync()
              .Result;
```

This resolve not only the problem of the searching about exact match, but also the issue which renaming a name on Sharepoint the update is being visible after 10/15 minutes (known issue).