# Graph SDK search drive items

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Graph SDK to search files in SharePoint. Is it possible to search them only by the name?

```
            var request = _graphServiceClient
                .Drives[id]
                .Root
                .Search($"{searched}")
                .Request();
```

The request above returns files that have the given phrase in content or metadata and I need to filter them by name in code. I would like to avoid this approach if possible.

Comment: Do you mean search by file name without extension?

Comment: it looks like [get item api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) doesn't support filter query, so I'm afraid you had to do it via your code.

Comment: Does this help? It looks quite similar to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67522784/2250152

Answer (score 0):

You can use search api like following

```
POST /search/query
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "driveItem"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "contoso"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the document for details

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files